# How do miners choose which transactions to include in a block?

Tags: mining, gas, private-blockchain

If I'm running a private chain with a block `gasLimit`: 100 and if I initiate 60 transactions, all with an equal `gas` value of 2, I assume only 50 transactions will be placed in the current block. If all the transactions reach the miner at the same time, which 50 of these 60 transactions will be added to the current block? Is there any guarantee that the remaining 10 transactions in the queue will be added to the immediate next block? How are queues managed?

Comment: Short answer, as specified in the dupe: for transactions of equal gas, they're ordered by nonce.

Comment: @Richard What if two transactions have the same nonce? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. However... The longer answer is that they are also ordered by the account from which they came (alphanumeric ordering), so nonce doesn't really have much affect on the final order except for transactions that came from the same account. I should add some more details to the answer I duplicated this one to, though the algorithm is quite involved. (And it _is_ linked to.)

Comment: Thanks! I will keep an eye on the original question/answer.